# show/hide issue. want to initial show in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am new in jquery. I just want display or hide the matched element. So I use slideToogle() function. my code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".show_hide").show();
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();

    $('.show_hide').click(function () {
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

here .show_hide class is link and .slidingDiv class div is content. I just want if load page the .slidingDiv content will initial show

Comment: "*I just want if I don't click link the .slidingDiv content always show not hidden in default.*" - then don't hide it to start with...i.e. remove `$(".slidingDiv").hide();`

Comment: So, why not remove this line: $(".slidingDiv").hide(); ???

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yw7sY/1/ ?

Comment: but i want hide. but i just want when the page load it shows .slidingDiv

Comment: @Jonathan your code work well but why <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='show_hide'>Show/hide</a> not work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

set the slidingdiv intially to 'display:block' , so when the page loads initially it will be  shown

```
             .slidingDiv
                {
               display:block;
               }


        $(document).ready(function () {      
                 $('.show_hide').click(function () {
                 $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
                        });
                   });
```

or just change the jquery code to

```
         $(document).ready(function () {
               $(".show_hide, .slidingDiv").show();    
               $('.show_hide').click(function () {
                    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
                     });
                   });
```

Comment: why was this downvoted?. i would like to know the mistake in the code to correct it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with CSS, he's doing `$(".slidingDiv").hide();`

Comment: @Pbk1303 doesn't hide of you link

Comment: ya but in the fiddle i changed the jquery code, i removed those lines, and changed it in css.

Comment: @emon: not able to understand your statement.